# Ajuda na exclusão e Edição em angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Boa tarde ! Não estou conseguindo criar a funcionalidade de editar e remover um objeto de um vetor com angular , alguém poderia me ajudar ? segue abaixo o código do controller e o service :

```html
angular.module("appOS").controller("CadastroServicoCtrl",function($scope, Servicos,$location,$timeout){
 
  $scope.servicos = Servicos.listar();
  
  $scope.adicionarServico = function(servico){
    $scope.exibirMsg = false;
    
    var id = $scope.servicos.length;
    servico.codigo = (id + 1);
    Servicos.adicionar(angular.copy(servico));
    delete $scope.servico;
    $scope.servicoForm.$setPristine();
    
      $timeout(function(){
      $scope.exibirMsg = true;
      $scope.mensagem = "Serviço Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
      }, 2000);
      
 };



});
```

```html
angular.module("appOS").factory("Servicos", function(){
 var servicos = [];
 return {
  listar: function(){
   return servicos;
  },
  adicionar: function(servico){
   
   servicos.push(angular.copy(servico));
   delete servico;
  },
  remover:function(id){
   
  }
 }

});
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de `CRUD` com todas as operações. Apesar de parecer um tutorial acredito que seja o que você precisa pra sanar suas dúvidas.

```js
var app = angular.module("Aplicacao", []);

app.controller("ControllerCliente", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.clienteSelecionado = {};
    $scope.clientes = [];
    $scope.novoCliente = true;
    console.log("O Controller iniciou.");

    $scope.cadastrar = function() {
      if ($scope.novoCliente) {
        $scope.clientes.push($scope.clienteSelecionado);
      }

      $scope.novoCliente = true;
      $scope.clienteSelecionado = {};
    };

    // Objeto no javascript trabalha com referência
    $scope.selecionar = function(indice) {
      $scope.novoCliente = false;
      $scope.clienteSelecionado = $scope.clientes[indice];
    };

    $scope.excluir = function(indice) {
      $scope.clientes.splice(indice, 1); // Apaga n registros de um vetor a partir de um índice
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Aplicacao">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerCliente">
    {{clienteSelecionado}}
    <br>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Cadastro de Cliente</legend>

        <div>
          <label for="edtNome">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" name="edtNome" ng-model="clienteSelecionado.nome">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="edtSobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
          <input type="text" name="edtSobrenome" ng-model="clienteSelecionado.sobrenome">
        </div>

        <div>
          <button ng-click="cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    {{clientes}}

    <table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Sobrenome</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes">
          <td>{{cliente.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{cliente.sobrenome}}</td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="selecionar($index)">Selecionar</button>
            <button ng-click="excluir($index)">Excluir</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Particularmente, eu te aconselho a não usar a Factory dessa maneira, principalmente pela sua variável estar dentro da factory, eu não sei como a sua aplicação funciona, mas se essa factory passar pelo sistema de injeção por ser chamada em outro lugar, ele deve acabar por zerar essa sua variável, mas nada te impede de ter os métodos na factory.

```
angular.module("appOS")
.controller("CadastroServicoCtrl",function($scope, arrayFactory){

  var ctrl = this;

  var arr = [];

  arrayFactory.add(arr, "valorAdd");

  arrayFactory.edit(arr, "valorAddModificado", null, "valorAdd"); // Edit por valor
  // arrayFactory.edit(arr, "valorAddModificado", 0, null); Edit por Index

  arrayFactory.remove(arr, null, "valorAddModificado"); // Remove por Valor
  // arrayFactory.remove(arr, 0, null); Remove por Index
});
```

---

```
angular.module("appOS").factory("arrayFactory", function(){
  return {
    add: function (arr, value) {
      arr.push(value);
      return arr;
    },

    edit: function (arr, newValue, index, oldValue) {
      if (index) {
        arr[index] = newValue;
        return arr;
      } else if (oldValue) {
        arr.forEach(function (item) {
          if (item == oldValue) {
            item = newValue;
          }
        });
        return arr;
      }
    },

    remove: function (arr, index, value) {
      if (index) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        return arr;
      } else if (value) {
        arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
          if (item == value) {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });
        return arr;
      }
    }
  }
});
```